# Magento full page cache hole punch for catalog pages

Tags: magento

Magento enterprise edition loads pages from cache without considering device.
If I take a catalog page on Ipad, same design will display on mobile(even though we have different design for mobile). When I disable full page cache cart works fine.

When I searched through forums and stack over flow, it says its due to magento full page cache and we need to pass getCacheId with custom string for the pages. Can you please give me an outline how I can do this for all catalog pages.

Comment: Can I use this to fix the issue?

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-block-caching/comment-page-1


Its written for product details page. I think I can edit and use for catalog page. Please advise. Also I assume I should disable full page cache when I implement inchoo code?

Answer (score 0):

When Full page cache  is delivered code takes parameters defined to gat a key value and fetch page dependent on that key.

If your Key parameters don't have a differentitor for ipad ve mobile vs desktop  and nor is your theme responsive( looks like its adaptive ) then you will face problem you have stated.

Comment: Do you know where I can find cache key-value pair and How I can use hole punch for all of catalog pages?

Comment: A container is associated with block.So if you understand keys associated with cache info by looking at XML and keyinfo functions you will get idea.Bit difficult to explain otherwise.